# How to create a Theme instance in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, resources, themes

There are some methods in android, for example *getColor* of *Resource* class, which ask for a *Theme* parameter. I didn't find a way how to create a *Theme* instance and therefore don't know what to send to *getColor* method as a *Theme*. I know that null is an option but I prefer to understand what can I do with the parameter (the meaning of *Theme* parameter in *getColor* method)

Comment: In most cases you will want to pass theme object from your current context: [`Context.getTheme()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getTheme()). You can also use [`ContextCompat.getColor(Context, int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/content/ContextCompat#getColor(android.content.Context,%20kotlin.Int)) instead of accessing resource object yourself.

Comment: @Pawel, but if i'm writing the following line of code:
*context.getResource().getColor(R.color.myRedColor, context.getTheme), is it possible in any way that *myRedColor* won't be find in  *xml Colors* and will be find under the theme? I will be happy to get a small (even stupid) example of this case

Answer (score 1):

If you're just referencing fixed colors from resource xml you won't notice a difference.

However you can use `getColor` to reference a color selector too, for example:

`color/singlecolor.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" />
</selector>
```

In this case there's reference to themed style attribute `colorPrimary`.

- if you pass `null` as theme you will receive value from your applications main theme
- if you pass `context.getTheme` you will receive value from your activitys theme

Of course your activity needs to have a custom theme that has different `colorPrimary` than applications theme itself to notice the difference.

Comment: thanks you!!!! So you are saying that if i'm writing *getColor(R.color.myFixedColor)* so the second parameters doesn't even matter?